# Как задать вопрос от главного предложения к придаточному?

Tags: спп, сложное-предложение

> Другой выдающийся российский правитель, Иван III Васильевич, в конце
> XV века пожелал перестроить Кремль, **ДЛЯ ЧЕГО** были приглашены
> итальянские мастера

Как задать вопрос от главного предложения к придаточному? Какой тип связи между ними?

Comment: Что было сделано Иваном 3/Кто был приглашён для того, чтобы перестроить Кремль? Для чего = для того, чтобы перестроить Кремль. Либо, что было сделано И3 для этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вместо вступления**

**Это краткий конспект учебника** по грамматике Кустовой (2023 год), его нет в Сети в открытом доступе. Он без «новаторства», то есть без моих собственных мыслей. И это как бы пример того, как можно **самостоятельно** пользоваться учебными материалами: ведь вряд ли кто-нибудь будет их находить и конспектировать для нас.

Учебник Кустовой **очень хорош** (у меня издание 2013 года), и не зря он постоянно переиздается. Там анализ дается очень **четко**, по определенной системе. Хотя он и для вузов, но содержание вполне **доступно** каждому в качестве справочного пособия **по грамматике**   При внимательном прочтении нужной темы всё быстро проясняется. (По Розенталю мы изучаем правописание, хотя грамматические справки там тоже есть.)

Вообще говоря, в Сети надо искать **авторитетные источники**, так как там очень много **«фантастики»**. Люди пишут собственные версии безо всяких ссылок, не указывая, на чем они основаны.

**Ответ**

*Другой выдающийся российский правитель, Иван III Васильевич, в конце XV века пожелал перестроить Кремль, **ДЛЯ ЧЕГО** были приглашены итальянские мастера.*

Это СПП с **распространительно-присоединительным придаточным**, связь подчинительная. СПП **расчлененного типа**: придаточное относится к основе предложения, а не к конкретному слову.

Вопрос в данном случае задать **сложно и по большому счету не нужно.** Вообще говоря,  вопросы обычно задаются при школьном анализе, а в этом учебнике определяются **отношения** между главной и придаточной частью (это и есть **грамматическое значение** сложного предложения).

Союзное слово (***для чего***) в придаточной части **вмещает** в себя содержание главной части. (В качестве дополнительного средства может использоваться **союз И**.) Выделяются **две разновидности** СПП – обстоятельственная и изъяснительная.

**Обстоятельственный тип**

**Значение цели:** *Управляющий закрыл сейф, **для чего** он и приходил*. Сравнить: У*правляющий приходил, **чтобы** закрыть сейф.*

*Иван III пожелал перестроить Кремль,  **для чего** были приглашены итальянские мастера*. Сравнить: *Итальянские мастера были приглашены **для того, чтобы** перестроить Кремль*. СПП с придаточным цели.

Также: *Иван III пожелал перестроить Кремль,  ***для этого*** были приглашены итальянские мастера.*  БСП с анафорическим наречием (***для этого***).

**Значение следствия:** *Комната темная, **отчего** цветы зачахли.* Сравнить:  *Цветы зачахли, **так как** комната темная*.

**Изъяснительный тип**
Применяется в том случае, если в главной части есть **слово с валентностью** на ситуацию: *Мы получили новое оборудование, **что** позволило продолжить работу*. *Растения начали болеть, **что** мы не сразу заметили*.

**Ошибки при анализе:**

(1) Нельзя считать возможной **замену** союзного слова с местоимением ***ЧТО***,  которое **ОТСЫЛАЕТ** к содержанию главной части (***для чего***),  наречием с анафорическим местоимением **ЭТО**, которое **УКАЗЫВАЕТ** на содержание первой (главной) части  предложения (***для этого, поэтому***).

(2) Ошибочно **называть** обстоятельственный тип СПП изъяснительным. В этом случае нет указания **на причинно-следственные отношения.**

(3) Не нужно **задавать** "изъяснительные" вопросы, если они **не проясняют** вид предложения, а также вообще подбирать вопросы.

Comment: В сети его (учебника) и вправду нет, как поискал. А где купить тогда можно?..

Comment: У Кустовой в 2005 году были соавторы, а в новых изданиях (с 2013 года) она единственный автор, поэтому защищает свои авторские права. Там нет упражнений, только теория, но некоторые темы существенно дополнены. Бумажный вариант мне не встречался, а электронную книгу можно заказать, если набрать в поисковике  Кустова Синтаксис современного русского языка. Курс лекций. Тогда они сами присылают рекламу. Стоит недорого.

Comment: 2013-ый лежит в сети, если что. Нельзя заменять "для чего" на "для этого"? Кустова в своем уме? Пример в студию!

Comment: Видимо, плохо искал 2013. Или название не то вводил?

Comment: @Sharon Можете помочь с анализом одного сочинения, дать свою профессиональную оценку?

Comment: @Алексей  Боюсь, что нет, извините меня.  Времени свободного совсем мало, да и сочинениями я не занимаюсь. Мои возможности - это грамматический анализ предложения по современным вузовским учебникам. То есть пределы обозначены именно так.

Comment: Жаль... а можете сказать по грамматике предложения что-нибудь? Говорят, что нагромождено, но я так не считаю...
*Таким образом, можно сказать, что оба примера дополняют друг друга, рисуя общую картину проблемы: первый пример показывает, что «быть как все» проще; второй – что обществом не принимаются выделяющиеся личности.*

Comment: Если только несколько слов о первом впечатлении... Я сторонник информативного стиля, а там читаемость текста – это очень важный показатель. Здесь действительно желательно записать предложение иначе, например разделить на два сообщения. Текст должен схватываться "на лету", без малейшего напряжения. Современные читатели привыкли к такому стандарту.

Comment: Но можно ли сказать что-нибудь в пользу этого предложения? (писанное пером не вырубить топором же)

Comment: Тут вообще существует чат какой-нибудь? А то так неудобно общаться...

Comment: @Алексей  На мой взгляд, предложение отличное, без каких-либо ошибок. Можно разделить и на два, конечно.

Comment: Алесей, чат есть, но я на минутку вот отвлеклась от работы. Еще раз смотрю на предложение. По-моему, его нужно просто разделить на две части,  то есть убрать двоеточие  и  поставить точку. Ну и  "можно сказать, что" вроде бы лишнее. В информативном стиле основной принцип – это "пиши и сокращай". Вот и Александр так думает, тоже вас проконсультирует, вы ему доверяйте :)

Comment: Да просто хочу апелляцию подавать - нужно создавать четкую позицию против "речевых ошибок", чтоб защищаться... А что скажете по поводу повтора слова «так»? В первом предложении выступает как вводное слово, в другом - как наречие. Предполагаю, что это посчитали тавтологией...

Comment: *Так, пред нами предстает картина: Алешка, желавший стать химиком, с легкостью принимает армейскую службу. Подобное «отсутствие воли» обсуждается Иваном Игнатьевичем: отец считает, что еще с детства его сын был как все. Так, словами директора, автор говорит, что проще существовать по руководящей команде и быть как все.*

Comment: Никаких идей нет?

Comment: Повтор "так" нежелателен, как и любые повторы. Кроме того, это слово должно быть уместным. Если это вводное слово, то у него синонимы: например, к примеру. Про первое "так" не знаю (это по контексту только видно). А второе "так" не выглядит корректным. И весь отрывок неясен. Мне, например, непонятна, о какой ситуации идет речь. А у вас  большое по объему сочинение и какой срок защиты?

Comment: 22 - срок защиты. Чтоб получить нужный балл, нужно иметь не более 1 речевой ошибки (аля повторы в моем случае). Если опустить повтор с "так" - не трогать его, то надо оправдывать другие повторы. По объему - 270 слов. Вот еще один пример повтора, но я его считаю оправданным, так как термины (уникальность, человек, общество, личность) тесно закреплены за проблемой произведения - уникальности человека. И все же комиссии надо предоставить вещественные доказательства.  ***Позиция автора довольно ясна: уникальному человеку сложнее «вписаться» в общество, ведь его личность противоположна обществу.***

Comment: Т.е. какие-то источники и так далее...

Comment: @Sharon, да, можно было спокойно заменить на другое вводное, но на меня что-то нашло спокойно использовать повторы, оправдываясь тем, что "так" представлено в разных частях речи - вводное слово и наречие, да и слово само по себе уникальное, которое позволяет сделать акцент на чем-то...

Comment: Алексей, неудобно смотреть текст в отрывках. Перешлите мне на почту, я посмотрю в целом. Но я задачу не  очень понимаю. Вам нужно защититься...но я вижу довольно много неточностей, которые надо исправлять. Но вам же не это нужно, вы хотите доказать, что у вас правильно.

Comment: Я бы и сам рад исправить, но писанное пером не вырубишь топором...

Comment: Я вашей почты только не вижу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146709/discussion-between--and-sharon).

Answer (score -1):

Задайте дополнительный (изъяснительный) падежный вопрос "для чего?". Относится к сказуемому "перестроить".